# CakePHP: Is the getLastInsertId method safe

Tags: cakephp, auto-increment

If I save a model, does the `getLastInsertId()` return the last insert ID or does it return the ID from the row I've just saved. In other words if I do this:

```
$this->Model->save($this->data);
__thisFunctionTakesAVeryLongTimeToExecute();
$insertId = $this->Model->getLastInsertId();
```

Does `getLastInsertId()` return the ID from the data I've saved 2 lines above. Or does it return the latest ID that's created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure about lastInsertId but... why dont you use `$this->Model->id` instead?? after saving the info, the last inserted id gets stored there

Answer (score 2):

I use `Model::getLastInsertID()` all of the time much the same way that you are attempting to use it and have had no issues.  `$this->Model->id` essentially does the same thing right after a save.

But keep in mind that `$this->Model->id` is writable (i.e. `$this->Model->id = <some_number>`) and doesn't always necessarily represent the ID of the record that you just inserted.  Whereas, `Model::getLastInsertID()` does.

Answer (score 1):

`Model::getLastInsertID` retrieves the last inserted ID from the current connection. So It's safe while you are not inserting from the same connection.

To make it a little bit more clear, I believe you have to think how to provoke this error because it's not so simple. Two different browsers on the same machine will use different connections. I'm not sure what should happen on the same browser with different tabs. As other one said before, I never had that problem.

The safest way, may be trough a store proceduce that returns the inserted id, but it's not the framework approach to do things.